# Get canvas context in Angular inside Web Worker

Tags: angular, canvas, render, web-worker

I'm using `platformWorkerAppDynamic` to render my Angular application.
However, I need to manipulate canvas context. I can create canvas, using `Renderer2` but **I can't find a way to call `getContext('2d')` method** for example or **draw an image to canvas**.
I get an error because `this.canvas.nativeElement` is an object of `WebWorkerRenderNode` but not the HTML element.

Can anyone help me with this issue?
Some tutorials of manipulation with DOM for Angular application which is rendered by means of webworker are also more than welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is a native limitation of the web platform, there is simply no HTMLCanvasElement, and thus no canvas context in web workers, at least not in the way you are looking for.

For worker threads, there is something called [OffscreenCanvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas), but the problem is that its `getContext` implementation is extremely limited currently, it's basically for WebGL only (so no `getContext("2d")`, and no corresponding methods, such as beginPath, moveTo, stroke, etc.):

```
let canvas = new OffscreenCanvas(512, 512);
let canvasCtx = canvas.getContext("webgl");
...
```

Your second option is to compute the raw image data yourself in a web-worker, and transfer it back to the main thread for drawing on a canvas. None of these solve your problem directly, but if you want to do canvas-related stuff in a worker, these are your only options.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I'll check

Answer (score -1):

You should consider using viewchild

first declare a template variable to your canvas element

```
<canvas #myCanvas width="100" height="100"> </canvas>
```

import the following into your component

```
import { ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
```

then, use it inside your component class

```
@ViewChild('myCanvas') canvasRef: ElementRef;
```

Now, declare it inside angular lifecycle hook

```
ngOnInit() {
  var ctx = this.canvasRef.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillStyle="red";
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,600,600);
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but no luck. `var ctx = this.canvasRef.nativeElement.getContext('2d');` won't work inside worker thread. You will get an error `this.canvasRef.nativeElement.getContext is not a function`

Comment: did you call it inside ngOnInit lifecycle hook?

Comment: Of course. This would work if I use `platformBrowserDynamic` for rendering, but I use `platformWorkerAppDynamic` thus it doesn't. This actually is the key issue.